# Launcher doesn't resize

Tags: 16.04, unity, resize, ubuntu-tweak

My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS launcher doesn't resize anymore :/ 
It seems locked. I tried to resize with Ubuntu Tweek, but doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell us first, what exactly did you try in order to resize your launcher, other than Ubuntu Tweak that is...
You could try going into settings...personal....appearance and doing it from there!  or perhaps you already tried that, and just haven't mentioned doing so?